# ng-repeat showing blank values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

**Question updated and solution provided.**
I'm getting a json feed from https://filters.rocks/embed/466.json.

The json is coming through in my scope but and I can view it in my pre tags but for whatever reason it's just not populating my ng-repeat.

```
app.controller('InstagramCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $http.get('https://filters.rocks/embed/466.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response;
            instagramSuccess($scope, $scope.items);

    });

    var instagramSuccess = function(scope, response) {
        if (response.data.length <= 0) {
            $scope.error = response.meta.error_type + ' | ' + response.meta.error_message;
            return;
        }
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
            $scope.items = response.data;

        } else {
            $scope.error = "This hashtag has returned no results";
        }
    };

}
]);
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="InstagramCtrl">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="instagram-list" ng-repeat="item in items">    
                        <li>
                            <small>{{item.data.feed.id}}</small>
                            <img ng-src="{{item.data.feed.approved_images.medium}}" width="250">
                        </li>

                    </ul>                       
                </div>
                <pre> filter.rocks {{ items | json }} </pre>
            </div>
        </div>           
    </div>
```

**Update**
I took bits and pieces from everyone and ended up with this ;
Controller

```
$scope.items = [];

      $http.get('https://filters.rocks/embed/466.json').then(function(response) {

            instagramSuccess(response);

    });

    var instagramSuccess = function(response) {
        if (!response.data) {
            $scope.error = response.meta.error_type + ' | ' + response.meta.error_message;
            return;
        }
        // check if data is defined if so, check objects are defined, then if array is defined. 
        if (response.data && response.data.feed && response.data.feed.approved_images && response.data.feed.approved_images.length ) {
            //if all good $scope.items becomes array
            $scope.items = response.data.feed.approved_images;

        } else {
            $scope.error = "This hashtag has returned no results";
        }
    };
```

**HTML**

```
                 <ul class="instagram-list" ng-repeat="item in items">    
                        <li class="instagram-item">
                            <small style="color:blue;">{{item.id}}</small>
                            <div bg-img="{{item.medium}}" width="250"></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Print {{items}} and see if you are calling the right child attributes. It is a common mistake that you would be receiving a Map but you proceed to iterate it as a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As madhairsilence indicated, you are treating items as if it is an array when it is not.  You may be looking to repeat through the approved_images as in:

```
<ul class="instagram-list" ng-repeat="item in items.feed.approved_images">    
    <li>
        <small>{{item.id}}</small>
        <img ng-src="{{item.medium}}" width="250">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Completely forgot that objects return a length of 0 or null, hence why nothing was coming through. I updated my question with he solution I got using your logic and modified it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML with following content...no need to change anything in your controller..you are looping on the wrong item

```
   <div class="panel-body">
          <ul class="instagram-list" ng-repeat="item in items.data.feed.approved_images">    
               <li>
                  <small>{{item.id}}</small>
                  <img ng-src="{{item.medium}}" width="250">
               </li>

         </ul>                       
    </div>
```

Comment: I expanded on your idea and added into my error check.

Comment: Yes..to check the length